# Reading immediately after write returns stale data on PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a toy project which consists of a PostgreSQL and a backend application that is running on my old computer, which I'd say kind of low-end by todays standards.

I have an operation that requires data to be inserted in 4 different tables in a transaction.

When I do the following from the client:

- Insert new Entity
- Fetch all Entities

The list returned from the backend doesn't contain the latest inserted data.

I couldn't understand why data hasn't become available as soon as I receive OK from the Postgres. Does it something to do with hosting the DB on a low-end machine?

Comment: _Does it something to do with hosting the DB on a low-end machine?_ No, it absolutely does not. It does, however, have everything to do with your application.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two possible explanations for what you observe:

1. You query the database in a concurrent database session *before* the data modifications have been committed.
2. You have a replication setup, modify data at the primary and run the queries at the standby. It takes a short while for the information to propagate to the standby.